# cakephp 3.8 login on any page instead of redirect to a login page

Tags: authentication, cakephp, oauth, cakephp-3.8

Normaly with the Auth component one has the ability to redirect to a login page if user isn't logged in. But I think there could be a better way not to redirect but to have a modal popup for login on any page where login is nessesary.
But how to view a popup on any secured page rather then redirect the user to a loginpage and then load and call back the previouse page??

Comment: Would you load the secured content and put the popup over it? That would not be secure. So, load no content and put a popup over it? Why not just redirect then?

Comment: You are right!. But you must see this situation:

One user come to a page which isn't secured. Normaly he can and should read everything! But if he/she click further to reach another (secured) page he/she should not redirect to another login page and then come back or redireced him to the desired page but the user should get a popup to login before leave this unsecured page and before come to a secured one. So the user is always on the unsecured site when he isn't logged in. I hope you understand what I meant :-)

Comment: In the Auth component you are able to define 
loginAction =>[
                'controller' => 'users',
                'action' => 'login',
            ]
That means you will be redirected if user isn't loggedin but instade of redirect I would like to have a popup BEFORE reaching the secured page to log in.

Comment: Any solution like this would require that the page you are on have some way to know whether the target page is secure before the browser starts redirecting. I guess you could do that by having an onClick handler that sends an Ajax request to the server to find out whether that page can be loaded, and presenting the popup if it can't.